# state is not getting updated from child callback

Tags: reactjs, state, lifecycle

I have Parent(A) and child(B) two components

```
function A () {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: 'Sam', age: '10' })

    function updateUser() {
        setUser({ ...user, name: 'DiffName'})
    }

    function updateUserAnotherFunc () {
        setUser({ ...user, age: '12'}) // here name is Still 'Sam'

    }   
}
```

Assume I passed these two callback functions as props into B, then B is calling these two function at the *very first time* B rendered, The call order is first 'updateUser' and then 'updateUserAnotherFunc', the problem is, even though I call `updateUserAnotherFunc` later at that time I can not see the updated name('DiffName') in the state

```
function B({updateUser, updateUserAnotherFunc}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    updateUser();
    updateUserAnotherFunc();
  }, []);
}
```

how I can get the updated name in 'updateUserAnotherFunc' ?

is there way to update state synchronously?

Comment: can you show us more real code of yours not just an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

setState works in an asynchronous way. That means after calling setState the this.state variable is not immediately changed.

so the new name you added in udpateUser is overriden by old user name in updateUserAnotherFunc.

so in order to make it work, you can maintain two state hooks one for name and another for age and update state. so that age update doesn't override name.

see Demo here: [alternative approach to solve your problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-pond-vdsqt)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my state is more complex than this, it contains an array of objects, actually I update one of that objects, so I cant divide the state

Comment: well then let me know if you finalized any other approach , i would like to know.thanks.